# Laravel 5 - check if mail is send

Tags: php, email, laravel, laravel-5

Is there a way to be a 100% sure that the email you want to send is actually delivered (I'm not talking about an email address that doesn't exist)?

Can you do an extra check? I'm working in Larevel 5.0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Mail::send(...)
```

And ***Error Reporting*** is

```
if( count(Mail::failures()) > 0 ) {

   foreach(Mail::failures as $email_address) {
       echo "$email_address <br />";
    }

} else {
    echo "Mail sent successfully!";
}
```

Comment: Hi spartan, isnt mail::send() asynch? how will the if statement catch all? sorry I couldnt find the api docs for this.

Comment: @AbdullaNilam Hi! What if while sending an email it returns the error, so how can you check it while sending an email?  For example, you have a weak internet connection or your connection has been stop or cut, it still returns an error.

Answer (score 1):

Are you checking `Mail::failures()` ?

Comment: Why did this get downvoted? Mail::failures() returns an array of failed emails after you've sent them.

Answer (score 0):

If you want 100% certainty, you should use a third party API such as [mailgun](https://mailgun.com/). Laravel supports them out of the box, and they offer in-depth tracking.