# How to check mail is sent or not in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, email, smtp

I'm currently working on laravel mail. I've sending email structure with attachment like this:

```
$document  = Document::find($request->document_id);

Mail::send('email.senddocs', array('project'=>$document->project->name,'type'=>$document->documentType->type), function($message) use($request,$document){

    $file_name = public_path().'/documents/'.$document->project->p_key.'/'.$document->file_name;

    $message->from('us@example.com', 'DDMS');
    $message->to($request->email);
    $message->attach($file_name);

});
```

I've already visited [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32882357/check-mail-is-sent-successfully-or-not-on-laravel-5). But, the process over there always returning success.

What I actually want is to know if mail is send or not. In my case, `Mail` sending can fail due to fake email like `akdjbaksdjf@jhbasdhadfs.com` or by some other errors occurred.

How can I know mail is sent or not ?

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel 5 - check if mail is send](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33096055/laravel-5-check-if-mail-is-send)

Comment: @jrenk Not working in my case

Answer (score 2):

This questions is asked several times here:
[Laravel 5 - check if mail is send](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33096055/laravel-5-check-if-mail-is-send)

You can use the failure method for this:

```
if( count(Mail::failures()) > 0 ) {

   foreach(Mail::failures as $email_address) {
       echo "$email_address <br />";
    }

} else {
    echo "Mail sent successfully!";
}
```

This only checks if a email was send. You can not handle not existing email adresses with this method.
You can use mailgun for this problem for example.

Another way is to use a php class which connects to a smtp server, and will check.

PHP class:
https://www.phpclasses.org/package/6650-PHP-Check-if-an-e-mail-is-valid-using-SMTP.html

Some Informationen of checking email adresses: [How to check if an email address exists without sending an email?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/565504/how-to-check-if-an-email-address-exists-without-sending-an-email)

Comment: @yfail Let me check

Comment: I've added mail as `jhbdajfsd@jhbasdjf.com` but says **Mail sent successfully!**

Comment: This also right. Cause Laravel don't check if the Mail exists. For things like that you have to use mailgun for example. You can only check if there is a problem sending an email or other things that may happened.

Comment: I've dumped the `count` of mail errors it shows **0**

Comment: Yes, because there aren't any errors. I told you, that laravel not checks if a email adress exists. It only does normal validation things. For something like this, you should use mailgun for example. Here is a good tutorial to get in touch: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/mail

Comment: Then, We can't check such things in laravel ?

Comment: No. To check if a email adress exists, you have to send one. This email will be rejected and returned back to your mailserver. Then you have to check in your mail server. Mailgun does this for you. You can also do more things ;)

Comment: can you add some details about checking valid email address ?

Comment: You can try this class: https://www.phpclasses.org/package/6650-PHP-Check-if-an-e-mail-is-valid-using-SMTP.html

Comment: Thanks for following up here and for your useful answer.

Comment: Read this topic, cause there are some more information about verfied email adresses. I could be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/565504/how-to-check-if-an-email-address-exists-without-sending-an-email

Comment: I've viewed that answer but i don't understand that.

Comment: What exaclty you don't understand?

Comment: How to check RCPT for given email

Comment: Here is a tutorial: https://ctrlq.org/code/20152-validate-email-address - But keep in mind that this is not a 100% way!